# Easiest way to escape the output of find?

Tags: shell, find, escaping

I want to do something like

```
find . -name "*whatever*" | xargs zip my.zip
```

but if the files I'm finding contain certain characters, this gets messed up, for example with spaces within the filenames. I guess I should escape the results. I couldn't quite understand from `man find` whether it could do this for me. So:

- Can I make `find` escape the results?
- If not, how should I escape them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Null separation was made for this exact case.

`find` can be instructed to separate its outputs with `NUL` characters (0's) via the `-print0` option.

`xargs` can be instructed that its incoming arguments will be `NUL` separated with the `-0` option.

Hence,

```
find . -name "*whatever*" -print0 | xargs -0 zip my.zip
```

Comment: As a side comment for anyone else wanting to use this for other things, if you have sufficiently many files, `xargs` may use multiple invocations of the target command.  In the case of `zip` this works fine, because a second invocation of `zip` will see the existing zip file and continue to add new files to it.  If you attempt to do this with `tar`, for example, you run the risk of not getting all your files because the last invocation of the command overwrote the previous archives.  You would need to use append mode (rather than create) to ensure that this did not happen.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question again what I stumbled upon it, and your answer :-P +1